# Erro de null-safety e dependência

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-database

Então, comecei em um estágio recentemente onde estou dando manutenção e criando novas features em um app mobile, uma dessas features é o usuário se registrar diretamente pelo app e não pelo DB do Firebase (no momento cadastramos os usuarios dessa forma). O código não recebe manutenção desde 2019...
Na parte que eu uso a sintax (User? user) me retorna este erro: This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.12.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'

Quando atualizo o sdk para o 2.12 o erro é resolvido só que que aparece muito mais... Já olhei documentação, youtube e tudo mais, minha esperança são vcs. Grato

```
import package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart;
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';


class AuthService extends ChangeNotifier{
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User? usuario;
  bool isLoading = true;

  AuthService(){
    _authCheck();
  }

  _authCheck(){
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user){
      usuario = (user == null) ? null : user;

    });

}}
```

Gabriel.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Você está tendo esse problema porque o sdk 2.12 introduziu null safety. Sugiro que você veja a documentação sobre como migrar para [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Answer (score -2):

Isso acontece porque seu código não era *null safe*. Se quiser adicionar a feature da forma que você disse, deve reescrever todo o código utilizando o *null safety*. Ou seja, vai ter que arrumar todos aqueles problemas. Utilize o link do rosário para entender melhor